How to see the users of an image
I am trying to clear up textures to clear up space on my computer. For a blend file, there are some images that I can't find being used by an materials, yet the images don't end up in orphan data. Is there a way I can see what is using the image so that I can know for sure it's okay to delete it?

I don't know how you can find what material use an image, but, but if you've deleted some materials, they will be removed when you'll close the file but their image texture will remain the next time you'll open the file because they are a level down in the hierarchy, close the file again and the image will be deleted for good.
